# Node.js - Get 2 equal expressions from the same file

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this regular expression:

```
var from = result.match(/^From\:(.*)/m)[1].replace(/^\s+/, '');
```

The problem is that I have 2 "From:" and I want to get both. How do I get the next "From:" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one statement with a lookbehind (?<=) which matches, but doesn't capture

> <s>var from = result.replace(/(?<=^From\:)\s+/mg, '');</s>

**Edit:** javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, so you need to do this:

```
from = result.replace(/^(?:(From\:)\s+|.*)/mg,"$1")
```

Comment: I get this error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=^From\:)\s+/: Invalid group

Comment: @donald. sorry I didn't realize that javascript didn't support lookbehinds. I've updated with tested code.

Comment: got the 2 froms, however, they are not in an array where I can read them. I need the second form in a string to edit. Thanks

Comment: you can just split the string on "\n"

Answer (score 0):

`result.match()` should return an array of strings. It looks like you are only accessing the result at index [1] of the array. You can iterate through this array to get both "From:" strings by storing the result of match() in a variable, and then calling replace() repeatedly.

Comment: it only returns the first from, not the second.